# rspec match_array recursively?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec

I have an rspec that looks like this:

```
expect(res).to match_array(expected)
```

And it's failing with this output:

```
the missing elements were:   [[:all_reports, [{:match=>"Tech", :title=>"Middle Tech Middle", :url=>"/report_sections/4267"}, {:match=>"Tech", :title=>"High Tech High", :url=>"/report_sections/4265"}]]]
the extra elements were:        [[:all_reports, [{:match=>"Tech", :title=>"High Tech High", :url=>"/report_sections/4265"}, {:match=>"Tech", :title=>"Middle Tech Middle", :url=>"/report_sections/4267"}]]]
```

My guess is that the problem is that the thing that needs to be re-ordered is 2 layers deep, and that's not what match_array does...

Do I just do a `match_array` on `res[0][1]` and `expected[0][1]`?

Comment: Until your post, I thought the matcher was simply doing `a1.sort == a2.sort` but after reviewing the source, it is _much more_ than that: https://github.com/rspec/rspec-expectations/blob/dc0ecfdc3f050f886d2b22e5554e9be32dfb1721/lib/rspec/matchers/built_in/contain_exactly.rb#L178

Answer (score 1):

This seems to work, but I'm not sure if it's idiomatic:

Since the dict actually has 2 fields, I used:

```
  expect(res[:all_reports]).to match_array(expected[:all_reports])
  expect(res[:this_report]).to match_array(expected[:this_report])
```